# Receiving wrong charset using curl in AppleScript to hand it over to Outlook on macOS

Tags: curl, encoding, outlook, applescript

I'm having one last problem, while building an AppleScript routine to set signatures in Microsoft Outlook concerning the signature's encoding.

This is very much broken down the essential part of the AppleScript part (It's much more like retrieving URLs, information of the logged in user, etc.)

So I'm using `curl` to fetch the source code of an HTML signature (works fine). The webserver does respond with an html document which has the following meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />` in the `<head>`-element. When calling the URL in a browser - everything works fine. Even when I put this into a signature in Outlook on Windows. So here everything should be fine.

The problem however is to pack it into Outlook on Mac.

```
set signatureName to "My Signature"
set sourceUri to "http://my.domain.com/my-signature.htm"
set sourceCode to (do shell script "curl -L " & sourceUri)

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    delete every signature
    make new signature with properties {name:signatureName,content:sourceCode}
end tell
```

So the signature appears in Outlook meaning that this works as well.

However, on the way something within the encoding seems to break somehow:

While the `curl` command retrieves the source code in correct encoding (I tested this directly on the command line by using `curl` and piping the result into `iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8`) it seems to be messed with, when arriving in my AppleScript variable.

I read that AppleScript now works internally in UTF16 and handles in- and outgoing stuff as UTF-8. So I tried various things calling shell scripts to use `iconv` and so on. However nothing leads to the desired result.

The signature/html markup contains several "special chars" however I will give a word as example, which only contains one, to not overcomplicate it:

What I expect (and works fine in browser -> ISO8859-1)

```
Öffnungszeiten
```

When I just execute the above AppleScript snippet this arrives in Outlook:

```
÷ffnungszeiten
```

When I add something like this

```
set sourceCode to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sourceCode & " | iconv -c -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8")
set sourceCode to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sourceCode & " | sed 's/ISO-8859-1/UTF-8/g'")
--- second line is only to change the charset within the meta tag in the head section to match actual encoding with it
```

in an attempt to transform `sourceCode` it results in

```
Ã·ffnungszeiten
```

in Outlook. These arriving chars doesn't even look like the "normal" encoding errors I normally encounter. I guess this is kind of a "chain-mess-up".

Does anybody have an idea what happens here and how to get around this?

*EDIT*
Right after posting this I just tried one thing, which leads to an working result:

I always tried the conversion in two/three steps like:

```
set sourceCode to (do shell script "curl -L " & sourceUri)
set sourceCode to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sourceCode & " | iconv -c -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8")
set sourceCode to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sourceCode & " | sed 's/ISO-8859-1/UTF-8/g'")
```

Now I just modified the first call by piping it:

```
set sourceCode to (do shell script "curl -L " & sourceUri &  "| iconv -c -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 | sed 's/ISO-8859-1/UTF-8/g'")
```

This results in the expected `Ö`-character in Outlook. However I intentionally want to use ISO8859-1 so I am still curious about a solution that keeps my original encoding.

Comment: @Mockman Yes - my fingers didn't want to hit this "v" I guess. Thank's for the hint, I've corrected it.

Comment: I don't think I understand character encoding well enough to say definitively but I don't see how this might work. Interesting problem though.

Comment: Hey, out of curiosity, have you looked at this while using the Satimage osax? With it, you can better handle (including force) an encoding when reading or writing text. Look for 'readtext' on [Satimage](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/dictionaries/dict_satimage.html#SatimageTextAdditions) for details. I can't exactly mimic your set-up but otherwise when I `read` a text file my new sig is '√ñffnungszeiten', when I use `readtext` then my new sig is 'Öffnungszeiten'.